# How to combine multiple searches into 1 table/graph?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I have two searches something like this:

```
"ns=my_project" message="*RESPONSE_CODE=200*" OR "*RESPONSE_CODE=400*" METHOD=API1 add|top RESPONSE_CODE
"ns=my_project" message="*RESPONSE_CODE=200*" OR "*RESPONSE_CODE=400*" METHOD=gAPI2 something_else|top RESPONSE_CODE
```

I want to combine them into one graph/table that will look something like this:
[image]

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: what have you already tried? What does the data look like?